# ERR_UNSAFE_REDIRECT when Laravel Passport redirect URL points to a Chrome extension

Tags: laravel, google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, laravel-passport

I've some trouble with authenticating a Google Chrome extension with my Laravel project. I used Chrome identity library for client-side and Passport in server-side. Everything work well till Passport tries to redirect to Chrome extension URL (as callback URL).

This is the client-side method:

```js
let httpBuildQuery = require('http-build-query');

    let auth_url = 'https://my-laravel-project/oauth/authorize',
  client_id = '<client-id>',
  redirect_url = "chrome-extension://<ext-id>/pages/panel.html",
  auth_params = {
      client_id: client_id,
      redirect_uri: redirect_url,
      response_type: 'token',
      scope: ''
  };

  auth_url += '?' + httpBuildQuery(auth_params);
    
  chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow({url: auth_url, interactive: true}, function(responseUrl) {
   console.log(responseUrl);
  });
```

Chrome gives me this error:
[Google Chrome console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Igo4f.png)

I even try to put auth URL directly in the browser but I get an ERR_UNSAFE_REDIRECT.

Everything should be set correctly, even in manifest.json. Does someone know why this happens? I really appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that Chrome considers safe only redirect with HTTP/HTTPS URL. The only way that I found to fix this problem is to create a login form based on [Personal access token method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport#personal-access-tokens).